# How do I give plain object an index signature

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this object:

```
const events = {
  i: 'insert',
  u: 'update',
  d: 'delete'
};
```

for some reason I am blanking on how to give the object an index signature - if I do this:

```
export interface EventsSignature {
  [key:string]: string
}

const events = <EventsSignature>{
  i: 'insert',
  u: 'update',
  d: 'delete'
};
```

that doesn't work, just overrides the object definition. Note I have the same problem when doing this:

```
export class OplogObservable {

  private uri: string;
  private coll: Collection;
  collName: string;
  isTailing = false;

  private subs = {
    all: new Subject<any>(),
    update: new Subject<Object>(),
    insert: new Subject<Object>(),
    delete: new Subject<Object>(),
    errors: new Subject<Object>(),
    end: new Subject<Object>()
  };

}
```

if I do `new OplogObservable().subs[type]` it will complain saying there is no index signature.

Comment: so what is the desired effect ? that `events` will have properties `I`, `u`, `d` and also an index signature to allow the addition of more properties ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir events could be an enum, but the subs example cannot really be an enum, so maybe think about the subs property.

Answer (score 2):

The object literal already has an index signature, it's just that you can't index by an arbitrary string, it needs to be a key of the type:

```
export class OplogObservable {

    private subs = {
        all: new Subject<any>(),
        update: new Subject<Object>(),
        insert: new Subject<Object>(),
        delete: new Subject<Object>(),
        errors: new Subject<Object>(),
        end: new Subject<Object>()
    };
    test(type: string) {
        this.subs['all'] // ok using a constant 
        let subs = this.subs;
        this.subs[type as keyof typeof subs] // ok if we use a type assertion on the key
    }
}
```

If you really want to index using an arbitrary string you could use a type assertion to any:

```
 (this.subs as any)[type]
```

Or use a helper function to create an object with both the properties and the indexer:

```
function eventsHelper<T extends { [name: string] :Subject<any> }>(subs: T) : T & { [name: string] :Subject<any> }{
    return subs;
}
export class OplogObservable {

    private subs = eventsHelper({
        all: new Subject<any>(),
        update: new Subject<Object>(),
        insert: new Subject<Object>(),
        delete: new Subject<Object>(),
        errors: new Subject<Object>(),
        end: new Subject<Object>()
    });
    test(type: string) {
        this.subs.all // props preserved
        this.subs[type] // ok if we use a simple string to index
    }
}
```